# C++ 2D Vector from a csv file

Tags: c++, csv, vector

I have this .csv file. It has 6 columns (separated by comma) and many rows. I want to make a 3D vector such that each row is in a vector and all rows are inside the 3D vector.

My code so far:

```
// open a file in read mode.
ifstream csv("test.csv");
string line;
vector <string> lineV;

if (csv.is_open()) {
        for (int i = 0; csv.good(); i++)
        {
            getline(csv, line, ',');
            lineV.push_back(line);
        }
}
else {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
}

// close the opened file.
csv.close();
```

Now, I have this vector lineV which has all the values in the .csv file separated by commas, like this:

> row1column1
>
> row1column2
>
> row1column3
>
> row1column4
>
> row1column5
>
> row1column6
>
> row2column1
>
> ...and so on

I thought of trying to iterate through the vector and passing the values to a new vector after every 6th value, but I don't know how to start.

Alternatively, if I change `getline(csv, line, ',');` to `getline(csv, line);`, I can get it row by row:

> row1column1,row1column2,row1column3,row1column4,row1column5,row1column6
>
> row2column1,row2column2,row2column3,row2column4,row2column5,row2column6
>
> ...and so on

But I will still have to split each row to its own vector...

Answer (score -1):

It may be easier for you to read the csv file by lines first (rows), then use a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to extract comma separated entities from each line.

```
// open a file in read mode.
std::ifstream csv("test.csv");
std::string line;
std::vector <std::vector<std::string>> items;

if (csv.is_open()) {
        for (std::string row_line; std::getline(csv, row_line);)
        {
            items.emplace_back();
            std::istringstream row_stream(row_line);
            for(std::string column; std::getline(row_stream, column, ',');)
                items.back().push_back(column);
        }
}
else {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good at c++. Could you explain your code a little more?

Comment: I don't get how your for loops work (without the int i=0...i++ thing), emplace_back and what's the difference between stringstream and istringstream?

Comment: And how do I iterate through this 3d vector?